# Set scrolling limits for fixed background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to set limits for how far a fixed background image can "scroll" down a page? Effectively, is there a way to change the background attachment to static once the the bottom of background image is say 10px away from the bottom edge of its div container?

In the code below, for example, how can I get the coral gradient (just a placeholder for an image) to stop scrolling with the page once it gets 10vh away from the border between the red and yellow divs? (CSS only is preferable, though I am also open to JS solutions)

```css
.red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: red fixed linear-gradient(lightcoral, lightcoral) 45vw 20vh / 20vh 20vh no-repeat;
}

.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aidan!

My approach uses an **img** tag instead of rendering it as background, and the magic is done with [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position) sitcky.

```
<style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    section{
        height:150vh;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .blue {
        background: rgb(23, 59, 71);
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .green {
        background-color: rgb(29, 82, 29);
    }

    .img{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: lightcoral;
        position: sticky;
        top: 50vh;
    }

</style>

<!-- body -->

<section class="blue">
    <div class="img"></div>
</section>

<section class="green"></section>
```

You can play with **padding** of its container to adjust the border offset.

Hope this helps.
Happy conding! ;)

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately I need it to be done using background images, not sticky images.